# Equivalence of singular matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove the following: $A$ has no inverse $\Rightarrow\det(A)=0$.

I know it is simple but I just do not know how...

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ has no inverse means that $\neg \exists B$ s.t. $AB=I_2$. And $\det(A)=0$ means that $ad-bc=0$. But thats all I get..

Gr

Comment: It may seem easier to prove the contrapositive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with matrices of order $2$, you can use the direct formula for the inverse of such matrices (see it [here](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm)).

It is easy to show that the formula there really provides the inverse, and that it actually provides that

$$\det A \ne 0 \Rightarrow \text{$A$ has the inverse},$$

which is equivalent to

$$\text{$A$ doesn't have an inverse} \Rightarrow \det A = 0,$$

which is what you want (a [proof by contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive)).

Comment: Oh great, so I can basically use the fact that the denominator must not equal 0 for an inverse to exist. Thanks!

Comment: @user61001 Not exactly. Be careful. When you prove that the formula really gives you an inverse, you actually get: **if $\bf \det A \ne 0$, there is an inverse**, but it doesn't say that $\det A$ must be zero in order to have the inverse. For all you know, there might be a different formula that can be applied when $\det A = 0$ (there is no such formula, but it's not visible from here). But you don't need that; you need the opposite direction: **if there is no inverse, then $\bf \det A = 0$**. This comes from using a contrapositive, which is explained in the second link in my answer.